# Is It possible to access service from out side the app folder in angular js 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I have create one angular js app in my asp.net MVC application like below folder structure,

DemoApp -> NG app folder on root

Inside "DemoApp" folder added app-modules.ts, app-routes.ts and app-component.ts files.

And also I have created one folder on root for some services and helpers like,

js/helpers -> on root

Inside "helpers" folder i have created one service (common-helper.ts) to perform some logic (actually I have many NG apps in my MVC application and I want to use this service in all the apps that's why I added this service separately ).

I want to use this service inside my "DemoApp" angular components, 
I added reference in app-module.ts file like,

import { CommonHelper} from 'js/helpers/common-helper';

but it gives me an error on console like,
"GET http://localhost:52428/js/common-helper 404 (Not Found)"

So is there any way or it is possible to access any services from out side the app folder ?

Comment: it looks like it tying to get the file common-helper.... but as i can see you call it helpers.js .. or rename it o try to import it correctly

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an issue everything is ok I try to move that common-helper.ts service inside "DemoApp" folder and it works well so i think we can't access any service or components form outside the app folder.

Any one have any other solution to access service from outside app folder?